# How to resolve ugly artifacts bending joints after posing?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Just learning here... I created a model in Makehuman and imported it into Blender. When I pose the model I get really ugly creases where the mesh appears to overlap:

[image: Reference Image]

How do I clean this up or avoid it? I'm not worried about animating or anything I just want it to look smooth.

Comment: Proper weight painting will help avoid problems like this

Comment: Add another bone in between the 2 bones with average rotation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically its best to first attempt to resolve the issue by weight painting.

That is to adjust the weights around the joint to improve the deformation.

- Adjust weight values by manually painting.
- Use the smooth tool to automatically re-distribute weights ([new in 2.76](https://developer.blender.org/rBc40205738b242f7501fea245f69cf1d7187e9d2c)), eg: [image: smooth result]
- Try the 'dual quaternion' option in the armature modifier
  *(helps avoid volume loss)*,
- When weight painting can't quite resolve all artifacts,
  try the  [corrective smooth modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/corrective_smooth.html) *(new in 2.75)*
  [image: corrective smooth]
- Corrective shape keys
  *Using a shape key to manually correct the distortion. While its involved to setup, it can be driven by bone and gives most control, This is typically used for more advanced rigging.*

---

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the "corrective" smooth modifier (not sure why) but the regular smooth modifier appears to releave some of the distortion. I will play with the weight / quaternion values as well once I'm further along.

Comment: @mister martin, its in 2.75 which isn't released just yet, but suggest trying the release-candidate, since I think it does exactly what you need *(assuming some simple tweaks to weights don't resolve)*.