# How can I animate an airplane wing bend without scaling the wing down?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have an airplane wing that I am trying to show bend at one point, but the scale keeps changing for the upper part of the wing. How can I keep the scale the same for both parts of the wing and still show it bending.[image]

Comment: Is the wing a rigid non-deforming element composed of some sort of hinge and two independent parts? If so might be better to model them as so, as two separate objects or at least two separate chunks inside the same mesh

Comment: I do want the wing to have a hinge. I believe you have seen my previous question about the miura fold, I am trying to use that miura mesh as my hinge. What is the best way to show that mesh folding and the wing bending, while still keeping its scale?

Comment: Animation is not really my area, but bending is expected to deform, even in real life. This is often fixed with [Corrective Shape Keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32943/how-to-resolve-ugly-artifacts-bending-joints-after-posing/32946#32946)